# Как в регулярное выражение добавить свои знаки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Только начал изучать регулярные выражения, и столкнулся с проблемкой, как два знака += и -= чтобы регулярка воспринимала его как один например в строке есть

```
a=1, a=+1, a=-1, a=b, a=b+100, a=b-100, b+=10, b+=+10, b+=-10, b+=b, b+=b+100, b+=b-100, c-=101, c-=+101, c-=-101, c-=b, c-=b+101, c-=b-101
```

вот например для а = 1 моя регулярка ([abc]=\d)

для a = +1 и a = -1 регулярка ([abc]=[+-]\d)

для а = b -> ([abc]=\w)

и так далее, но когда дохожу до b += 10 или b += B, c-+101 я сбиваюсь, и у меня возникает вопрос как сделать чтобы +=, -= искало как один символ и как объединить все регулярки в одну? Буду очень благодарен за любую подсказку, спасибо!

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, ту задачу, которая стоит перед вами. Нынешнее условие вполне подходит под формулировку [«Ошибка XY»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709)

Comment: `(\w+)([+-]?)=([+-]?\w+)(?:([+-])(\w+))?` - https://regex101.com/r/l586jS/2

Comment: Калькулятор делаете? Использовать регулярки для этого - гиблое дело. Пишите сразу правильно. Используйте рекурсивный спуск и т. п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точно также как вы ищете `[abc]`, только с одним нюансом, что `+` надо экранировать `\`. Для пары `+=`, `-=` выражение `[\+-]?=`

Строка из примера покрывается следующим выражением.

```
[abc][\+-]?=b?[-\+]?\d*
```

Если есть зависимости между тем какие знаки могут встречаться справа, если что-то было слево, то выражение усложнится и понадобятся `<lookahead>`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили)